# Transparent redirection from domain to subdomain

Tags: htaccess, redirects, dns, apache

I have a main domain name : `maindomain.com`, on which I can access DNS configuration and current linked server (only files, not configuration) and a "cdn" domain (not one the same domain) `cdn.domain.com` on which I can access nearly everything

I want to transparent redirect request to subdomain (i.e. maindomain.com still in adress bar but cdn.domain.com reached) to reach my 
website on symfony

What I tried :

**A 301 Redirect : (.htaccess)**

```
 RewriteEngine On      
 RewriteRule (.*) http://cdn.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

But this is not transparent as the URL change

**A Proxy redirect : (.htaccess)**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://cdn.domain.com/$1 [P]
```

But this doesn't seems to be activated on main server

I have some other solution to try, but I don't know if this could work and to avoid breaking the server I would like to know if this could work.

**Edit server name in configuration and set DNS**

```
 <VirtualHost *:80>
     ServerName maindomain.com
 </VirtualHost>
```

`maindomain.com` intead of current `cdn.domain.com`.
 And make DNS pointing to the server IP.

Can this configuration break other subdomains?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43632105/transparent-redirection-from-domain-to-subdomain

Externalise Symfony assets

As I don't have enough space on `maindomain.com` current server, I wanted to 
 know if I could only store the whole site structure except assets (a
 part of `web/` directory ? And how this would work for file upload ?

Furtherome is this viable (time complexity) with an external database
 (stored on `cdn.domain.com`) ?

Comment: There's no such thing as a transparent redirect.

Comment: @SimonHayter An "internal redirect" is _transparent_ to the user. (?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Transparent Redirects do not exist on planet Earth*

As mentioned in the comment there's no such thing as a transparent redirect, it either redirects or it doesn't.

---

*CNAME Records for MASKING Domain*

The method that your most likely looking for is a DOMAIN MASK, which doesn't redirect but fetches the content from the original domain without changing the website address. This is normally done using a CNAME record that points to the main domain.

---

*Apache Multiple ServerAlias*

The other option is that rather than using a MASK or Redirect you can simply tell your Apache to host the same content on both domains using multiple ServerAlias's, for example:

- `ServerAlias *.exampleA.com *.eampleB.com`